# How to create a WebClient-object in a spring application with oauth2

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

I'm developing a spring application (client) that is secured with an OAuth2 provider. This application should do some REST calls to another spring application (resource server). For performing the REST calls, I will use spring's WebClient.

I therefore try to create a bean of type WebClient as can be found in several blogs.

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
             new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations,
                new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("myprovider");
        return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
    }
}
```

When starting the application, I get the following error:

```
The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'clientRegistrationRepository' in 'ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration' not loaded because NoneNestedConditions 1 matched 0 did not; NestedCondition on ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration.NonServletApplicationCondition.ServletApplicationCondition found 'session' scope


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' in your configuration.
```

As several websites recommend exactly this code for generating a WebClient instance when using OAuth2 authentication, I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong?

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue. I changed the code as provided in the video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1N-xwmoN83w&t=1569s and that worked

```
@Bean
 public WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository , OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
             new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction (clientRegistrationRepository , authorizedClientRepository);
        return WebClient.builder().apply(oauth.oauth2Configuration()).build();
    }
```

Hope that helps.